# Printing nodes in XML in C

Tags: c, xml

I tried printing the nodes in the sample file. But i Keep getting a (text) printed after every node. Please help..

See the images tagged for information: [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m1ws.png) [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBrhd.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <libxml/xmlmemory.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv){

  xmlDoc         *document;
  xmlNode        *root, *first_child, *node, *sibling, *grand_child, *node2, *node3;
  char           *filename;


filename = argv[1];

document = xmlReadFile("sample.xml", NULL, 0);
root     = xmlDocGetRootElement(document);

fprintf(stdout, "Root is <%s>\n", root->name);


first_child = root->children;
for (node = first_child; node!=NULL; node = node->next){ 
     fprintf(stdout, "\t Child is <%s>\n", node->name);
     grand_child=node->children;

        for (node2= grand_child; node2!=NULL; node2 = node2->next){
            fprintf(stdout, "\tGrand_Child is <%s>\n",node2->name);
            sibling=node2->children;

            for (node3= sibling; node3!=NULL; node3 = node3->next){
               fprintf(stdout, "\t Sibling is <%s>\n",node3->name);
            }

        }
}
return 0;}
```

Comment: Please do not post code as images. Post it as text within the question body so that others can copy it and also because external links may not always be available. Also, please clarify what exactly your question is. "But i Keep getting a printed after every node" - that does not make grammatical sense and is not a question. So it is not clear what your problem is.

Comment: code is there. And as you can see from the image, when node are printing, there is a node stating "text" getting printed after every time. why is this?

Comment: Those are the name of the nodes: *text*node for the textual content (it does not have an explicit node), then the nodes. [libxml doc](http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/ar01s04.html) says you should use `xmlNodeListGetString` to get the string representation of the contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the text nodes then only print the nodes with type `XML_ELEMENT_NODE`. That is, the print code should first check the `type` field:

```
if (node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) {
    fprintf(stdout, "\t Child is <%s>\n", node->name);
}
```